# What is the Partiton Key value when it's null?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I've got records that were the result of bad data where the Partition Key is `null` and I need to clean them up, but I've been unsuccessful so far.

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

```
 var scriptResult = await _dbClient.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<dynamic>(
                GetStoredProcLink("BulkDelete"),
                new RequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(""), EnableScriptLogging = true },
                "select * from c where c.documentDbType = "SomeValue"");
```

I've also tried used `Undefined.Value` as the parameter to `new PartitionKey()`.

I ripped the stored proc from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/bulkDelete.js#L5) and haven't changed anything yet.

Note: This is a partitioned collection if it was not obvious (by `/companyId`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null, Undefined, and empty string are all different values in Cosmos DB. You need something like: `new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(null) }`

Comment: Whatever is passed to the PartitionKey constructor - is that evaluated in JavaScript as == (or coerced at all)? Is there a place I can see the mapping for what happens to the type that gets passed in?

Comment: This is not JavaScript, but the partition key value sent over the wire has bits reserved for the data type of the partition key value: string, Boolean, int, null, undefined, along with the actual value. Both have to match on the server side

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try and accept when validated

Answer (score 2):

I just hit this issue when migrating to new database level throughput provision. This is syntax that got me up and running again when my models did not contain the specified partition Key property:

```
new RequestOptions() {
   PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(Undefined.Value)
}
```

Ref:
https://www.lytzen.name/2016/12/06/find-docs-with-no-partitionkey-in-azure.html

Comment: That didn’t work for me at the time. That could have changed with subsequent sdk updates though

Answer (score 0):

In the new Cosmos API for .NET (https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3). You'd be using `PartitionKey.Null`. There is also a `PartitionKey.None` option for when it was not set at all.